# How to change a prop from a child?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue.js 2.5 and i have a list. Each item has an button for toggle the details. If i click on one button, all details from the other items should be closed and the new has to be opened.

Here is a piece of my code:

Root:

```js
<template lang="pug">
    template(v-for="item in data")
        item-template(:item="item", :details_visible.sync="details_visible")
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
                details_visible: false
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
            this.$on('close-all-event', function() {
                this.details_visible = false
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Child:

```js
<template lang="pug">
    .child
        span.button(@click="toggleDetails") More Details


        // Here are more details!!!!
        details-template(v-if="detailsOpen", :item="item")
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            item: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            details_visible: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },

        data: function() {
            return {}
        },

        methods:
        {
            toggleDetails: function (event) {
                // Close all Details from other Items
                //this.$parent.$emit('close-all-event')


                // Toggle Dummy... Only true...
                this.$emit('update:details_visible', true)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

With this code sample all details were opened... How can i modify the code, that only the details of one child are opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a  property `current_visible` and set it to null in the parent component. This `current_visible` propertied shall hold the currently opened details view item. Pass of as a prop to every child Component.

```
<template lang="pug">
    template(v-for="item in data")
        item-template(:item="item", :current-visible="current_visible")
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
                current_visible: null
            }
        },
        mounted()
        {
            var self = this;
            this.$on('update-current-visible', function(ev) {
                if(current_visible == ev){
                    self.current_visible = null;
                }else{
                    self.current_visible = ev;
                }

            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

In your child component check this `current_visible` against any `item.uniqueProperty` to display  more details.
When more details button is clicked emit an event passing `item.uniqueProperty` along with the event.

```
<template lang="pug">
    .child
        span.button(@click="toggleDetails(item.uniqueId") More Details


        // Here are more details!!!!
        details-template(v-if="current-visible === item.uniqueId", :item="item")
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            item: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            current-visible: [String, Number]
        },

        data: function() {
            return {}
        },

        methods:
        {
            toggleDetails: function (id) {
                this.$emit('update-current-visible', id)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

NOTE: look out for any typos answered this from my tablet